# Returned date of paypal payment agreement

Tags: laravel-5, paypal-sandbox

In laravel 5.8 app working with paypal/rest-api-sdk-php making payment agreement I  retrieved data from paypal server
with date in

```
2019-11-09T08:00:00Z
```

format
I need to convert it to mysql format. I think I can use str_replace function to convert to mysql format, but I am not sure if it is a good way?
What type of format it support and what is the proper way for converting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strtotime function

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

to convert it to date time
and convirt it to common mysql format:

```
$start_date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```